# mvc mini profiler (1.4) & IIS

Tags: iis-7.5, mvc-mini-profiler

The solution works great with cassini but as soon as I make it run into IIS (7.5 on Windows 7 / 64), it stops working.  All js & css file are never downloaded and the script fails.  I looked into the `MiniProfilerHanler`, the `GetHttpHandler` method is called for each required js & css but the `ProcessRequest` method never runs.

The same behavior is observed using the sample.mvc project that goes along with the mini profiler sources.

Comment: I'm running on iis in win 7.  This must be a config issue

Comment: Is the app pool in IIS running in classic or integrated mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went to Program/Feature control pannel and clicked add remove windows feature.  There I saw that under IIS, ASP.Net was not selected (all my sites worked like a charm) and checked it.. and Voila ! Don't ask ;-)

Answer (score 0):

this is an older question but if you are still trying to get this to work try adding this to your web.config

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

not really the best solution but it works