# StackExchange MiniProfiler UrlRoutingModules does not implement IHttpHandlerFactory

Tags: web-config, url-routing, mvc-mini-profiler

Miniprofiler on my site has stopped working.  In Chrome console, I get a 500 error on:

```
/mini-profiler-resources/includes.js?v=4.0.0.0
```

The error is:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule does not implement
>   IHttpHandlerFactory or IHttpHandler.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.

My web.config file has the following relevant lines:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="MiniProfiler" path="mini-profiler-resources/*" verb="*" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>
    <modules>
      <add name="DynamicURLRewrite" type="C3.Code.Controls.Application.Rewriting.URLRewriter" />
      <remove name="TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule" />
      <add name="TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule" type="Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation.TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule, Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation" preCondition="integratedMode,managedHandler" />
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
```

Comment: What is the value for `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests` in your `web.config`?

Comment: What version of IIS are you running? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/980368/a-update-is-available-that-enables-certain-iis-7-0-or-iis-7-5-handlers

Comment: @TarunLalwani that key is not specified in my web.config

Comment: @OluwafemiSule 10.0.15063.0

Comment: @OluwafemiSule also cannot install the hotfix, "The certificate for the signer of the message is invalid or not found"

Answer (score 1):

Please add below

```
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>
```

To `web.config` and see if it helps? If that doesn't work then check if you are able to access the files using localhost

```
http://127.0.0.1:<port>/mini-profiler-resources/includes.js?‌​v=4.0.0.0
```

If nothing works give uninstall and reinstalling MiniProfiler also a shot. Sometime re-installations do wonders

Comment: Can you check if `http://127.0.0.1:<port>/mini-profiler-resources/includes.js?v=4.0.0.0` works? Use the port configured

Comment: See if this helps ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6555533/mvc-mini-profiler-1-4-iis

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: Reinstalled Miniprofiler and got it working again now.  Not sure why that fixed it.  IF you want to edit your answer to suggest uninstall/reinstall I'll mark it as correct as you tried to help :)

Comment: @TomGullen, glad it works for you now :-). Answer updated